# In operation for StringExpression

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl

I am working on SpringBoot with JPA repository. I am using querydsl for dynamic search criteria.

I am able to implement equals, not equals, like commands.The only issue is with "IN " expression.

Like

```
public BooleanExpression like(String str)
```

Which is working fine. Can anyone suggest to me what I have to use for "IN"

Thanks,
Sri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BooleanExpression` is a `SimpleExpression` which has a method `public BooleanExpression in(T... right)` that takes a set of values and `public BooleanExpression in(Expression<? extends T>... right)` that takes a set of expressions.

You can wrap any `Expression` in a `SimpleExpression` using its constructor: `new SimpleExpression<>(expression)`.